# SQL Server: How to handle two different cases in Where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, where-clause

I have a stored procedure in SQL Server 2008 that is used to fetch data from a table.

**My input parameters are:**

```
@category nvarchar(50) = '',
@departmentID int
```

**My Where clause is:**

```
WHERE       A.departmentID = @departmentID
AND         A.category = @category
```

Is there any way I can apply a Case statement (or something similar) to this Where clause to say that it should only check for the category match if @category is not '' and **otherwise select all categories**?

The only thing I could think of here is to use the following. Technically this works but then I can't check for exact category matches which is required here:

```
WHERE       A.departmentID = @departmentID
AND         A.category LIKE '%'+@category+'%'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can modify your `WHERE` clause as follow:

```
WHERE A.departmentID = @departmentID
  AND (@category = '' or A.category = @category)
```

Comment: This is perfect - exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot - will accept as soon as I can ! :)

Answer (score 2):

```
WHERE A.departmentID = @departmentID
  AND ((@category = '') or (@category <> '' AND A.category = @category))
```

This should give you what you want as a result set, it basically doing a check for either a blank category which should then return all results for the department id or just the category specified in the parameters.

Comment: Thanks for this as well ! Just saw that the other answer is enough in my case as category cannot be empty in the db.

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
if(LTRIM(RTRIM(@category))='')   --if string is empty then set it to NULL
set @category=NULL

select * from tbl_name A
WHERE       A.departmentID = @departmentID
AND         A.category = @category
(AND         A.category LIKE '%'+@category+'%' OR @category IS NULL)
```

as HERE if we specify NULL, right side `OR` condition will returns true
 Hence it gives Correct results if we specify `@category NULL OR ''` (empty)

Answer (score 0):

Please also consider for null value if you pass from front-end

```
WHERE A.departmentID = @departmentID
  AND ( ( isnull(@category,'') = '' or  A.category = @category )
```